# Kotlin Log.i and Log.e errors

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm doing a basic training for Kotlin and Android Studio (4.1),

The training I follow is from 2018, may be already a bit old but I don't get why so basic function would not work.

I'm having a hard time trying to get logs to display in the "6:Logcat"

Here is my code:

```
package fr.benoitexample.blocnote

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity import android.os.Bundle import android.util.Log import android.view.View

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun addButtonTouched(button:View) {
        Log.i( tag:"banane", msg: "Coucou")
        Log.e( tag:"banane", msg: "Coucou")
    }

}
```

I'm getting this kind of error:

```
e: C:\Users\Benoit\AndroidStudioProjects\BlocNote\app\src\main\java\fr\benoitexample\blocnote\MainActivity.kt: (15, 21): Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)
```

Comment: Do you have the logger set to the appropriate log level? You can choose between "error" ,"warn, "info" and so on

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that. The error displays when building app.

Comment: Which line is line 15?

Comment: Log.i( tag: "banane", msg: "Coucou")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Log methods in android.util.Log take 2 String parameters (and optionally a Throwable as a third param) - you should write it like this:

`Log.i("banane", "Coucou")`

Answer (score 2):

You can't call Java methods with parameters name in Kotlin file

just simplify write this:

```
Log.i("banane", "Coucou")
```